# How to listen for keydown Enter and mouse click in a MDC menu?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, mdc-components

How do I listen to keydown Enter and mouse click for an item in an MDC menu? Do I have to setup `.addEventListener` for both these events on the menu item? Or is there another way (similar to `<button>` event handling)?

There is a mysterious mention of "handleKeydown(evt: Event) => void" in https://material.io/develop/web/components/menus, but no explanation of how and when to use it.